# Get the reason for failure and fetch the details from a keyword in RobotFramework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using **ExecutionResult** and **ResultVisitor** from **robot.api** to fetch the Testcase and keyword which causes the failure. But I'm not able to:

1. Print the reason for the failure. E.g., Suppose I've a failure something like this. I should be able to print the reason as ***Call not Found on Agent Desktop***

   [image]
2. Fetch the details from a keyword in the failed testcase. In my case, I should fetch the Arguments provided to a keyword and returned output from that keyword, which is part of the teardown.

```
*** Keywords ***

Teardown Keyword
    [Arguments]   ${arg1}  ${arg2}
    ${output}=  <Some execution here>
    [return]    ${output}
```

Here I should fetch the values of **${arg1}, ${arg2} and ${output}**

This is my sample code for reference:

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor
class Visitor(ResultVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.failed = []

    def end_test(self, test):
        if test.status == "FAIL":
            self.failed.append(test)

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.visit(visitor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Understand how the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) works and how to terminate visiting unwanted branches. From the [API documentation](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.result.html#robot.result.configurer.SuiteConfigurer.start_test), you can explicitly return `False` at any node level if you do not want to visit further down the result tree.

Use other visitor steps like `start_keyword` and `end_keyword` to visit each keyword and see which keyword failed.

Eg:

```
def start_test(self, test):
    if test.passed:
        # Not interested in passed test cases. 
        # So we can stop further visiting by returning False.
        return False
    # start_keyword for keywords in this test case 
    # would be called only if this test case has failed


def start_keyword(self, kw):
    # We are in a keyword of a failed test case
    if kw.passed:
         # Even though the test case might have failed, 
         # the keyword might have still passed. 
         # Since we are not interested in passed keyword, 
         # return False to stop visiting further.
         return False 
    # end_keyword for this keyword would only be called if this keyword has failed.

def end_keyword(self, kw):
    # We are in a failed keyword
    # Add your required logic here.
    if kw.type == robot.model.keyword.Keyword.TEARDOWN_TYPE and kw.name == 'your keyword':
        print("keyword args:", kw.args)
```